# jQuery equivalent selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are the following exactly equivalent? Which idiom do you use and why?

```
$('#form1 .edit-field :input')
$('#form1 .edit-field').find(':input')
$('.edit-field :input', '#form1')
$(':input', '#form1 .edit-field')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use either #2 or #4:

```
$('#form1 .edit-field').find(':input')
$(':input', '#form1 .edit-field')
```

Both of the above are essentially the same. Behind the curtain when you specify a context this is what's happening anyway:

```
jQuery( context ).find( selector );
```

The reason I would avoid #1 and #3 is because they're both significantly slower than #2/#4.

---

EDIT: Just did a quick test:
1000 input elements using YOUR selectors:

```
$('#form1 .edit-field :input')            // 55ms
$('#form1 .edit-field').find(':input')    // 21ms
$('.edit-field :input', '#form1')         // 47ms
$(':input', '#form1 .edit-field')         // 18ms
```

Comment: It's a bit strange that the first form is so slow, but once browsers support querySelector/querySelectorAll it may become more efficient.

Comment: Interesting; I never would have looked for such a significant performance difference. Good find.

Comment: Strange, but good to know. I wonder then, how would $('#form1').find('.edit-field').find(':input') perform. If your measurements are valid, I would expect this form to be even better...

Comment: these are some interesting benchmarks. thanks for the time and effort on this. i have been recently been using deeper context for selectors and this indicates that tends to run faster

Comment: What browser are these benchmarks from? Just tried FF3 and #2, #3 and #4 perform the same. #1 is slowest by about 25% more.

Comment: They're from FF3 ... I know that they may not be accurate - but if you think about it #2 and #4 should be the fastest because jQuery doesn't have to do so much string splitting... (and whatever else it does behind the scene)

Answer (score 4):

The first two are equivalent when comparing element selection.  However, the second form, when used in a command chain with a correspoding `end()` call, can be used to select further child elements within "#form1 .edit-field", i.e.:

```
$('#form1 .edit-field').find(':input')
   ...
.end().find(':hidden')...
.end()...
```

I'm uncertain about the second two forms, actually, I beleive they are not valid.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on the docs, the correct syntax would look like this:

```
$('.edit-field :input', $('#form1'))
$(':input', $('#form1 .edit-field'))
```

Either way, IMHO these are less consise ways of saying the same.

In summary, generally I'd stick to the first form, unless you exploit the advantage of the second to traverse further children, as explained above.

Comment: +1 for end() too, and all the originals are valid as provided. but then your corrections happen to be valid also :)

Answer (score 0):

The more I code in jQuery, the less I use selectors and the more I traverse instead. I would do:

```
$('#form1').find('.edit-field').find(':input')
```

It's longer, but conveys the selection process better with a bit more meaning for each step. Traversing is more favorable for chaining, and it makes end() useful.

Comment: That's not really traversing, per se.

Answer (score 0):

I would use different forms based on what I already have and what elements I also need to work with. For example, if I need to work with other fields in the same form, I'll save a reference to the $('#form1') to save searching for it multiple times.