# Help me optimize this selector? $('#data div.item:has(div.video_guid:empty)')

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, selector

It's currently not so slow as to make the site unusable, but in mobile safari on the iphone there is a noticeable lag. Is there a simpler way to do this?

"Find div.items that have an empty div.video_guid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there div's with a class video_guid anywhere else on the page? If not, you could simplify it to:

```
$('div.video_guid:empty');
```

The only difference between your selector and mine is that yours would match the parent `div.item` while mine would match the actual `div.video_guid`. To get around this, once my selector matches, if you want to perform operations to the parent `div.item` you could just do:

```
$('div.video_guid:empty').each(function() {
    var container = $(this).parents('div.item');
    // do something to the containing div
});
```

All things considered, I would expect that to perform better..

Comment: Yes these are the only div.video_guid:empty on the page. I was under the impression though that specifying the container in the selector aided performance, ie: 

$('#thecontainer div.video_guid:empty');
OR
$('div.video_guid:empty','#thecontainer');

I'll see if I can run some tests, thanks!

Comment: That is actually correct. I'd probably change mine to have a second argument of #data

Answer (score 0):

Read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604097/jquery-equivalent-selectors/604250#604250). According to this,

```
$(‘div.item:has(div.video_guid:empty)’, '#data')
```

should be faster. Strange, but apparently measurable.